# SIM900 module not reading Sim Card

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I am using GPRS Shield for Arduino Uno with SIM900 module on it. I am able to communicate with the module just fine (using AT commands), but whenever I try to use a command which involves sim card (like AT+CCID) I get a message saying ERROR and that's it (while AT+CCID=? returns OK as it should).

So I wanted to ask can it be that I am missing out on some parameter on SIM900 module that would allow using sim card? And is it possible somehow to do a hard reset on all module's parameters (in the documentation a command ATZ is mentioned, but it doesn't seem to reset all parameters)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try the SIM card in a phone

Comment: The SIM card works just fine in my phone (it has PIN disabled as well). Also tried using different SIM cards on the SIM900 module, with same effects.

Comment: The "standard" modem reset string is `AT&F0` - though whether the SIM900 supports that or not I have no clue.

Comment: Even after doing the factory reset with `AT&F0` command, I get same results...